# Expected struct std:vec:Vec found struct std:collections:hash_map:Keys

Tags: rust

I have the following `school` object

```
{"classrooms" : {"physics":"3210", "chemistry": "4310"}}
```

When I print out `school.classrooms`, then it returns as

`let class_list = school.classrooms.keys()` which returns `[physics, chemistry]`

Now, I need to pass `class_list` in the struct as follows, but I am stuck.

```
Hierarchy  {
    class_list
})
```

Struct is formed as follows:

```
#[derive(Clone, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Hierarchy {
   pub class_list: Vec<String>
}
```

then I am getting the following error

> expected struct std:vec:Vec found struct
> std:collections:hash_map:Keys

Comment: Have a `Vec<String>` or `HashMap<String, String>` as a field.

Comment: Please find my updated question, where I included the error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Keys` is an iterator over the keys of a HashMap. If you want to store it in a struct, first collect it into a `Vec`:

```rust
let collected: Vec<_> = school.classrooms.keys().cloned().collect();
let my_struct = Hierarchy {
    class_list: collected
};
```

Comment: how do you form the struct? Becuase `Vec<_>` is not allowed in type signatures in the struct.  `#[derive(Clone, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Hierarchy {
   pub class_list Vec<_>
}`

Comment: The struct should be `Vec<String>`, but your variable can be either `Vec<_>` or `Vec<String>` due to rust's type inference.

Comment: Now, I am getting the following issue `expected struct std:string:String, found &std:string:String`

Comment: You should either move the hashmap and `school.classrooms.into_iter().map(|x| x.0).collect()` or clone the iterator with `school.classrooms.keys().cloned().collect()`.